# Supress submit event / Submit button enabled only if javascript is disabled

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have some client-side JavaScript validation on a form. It works great. But I want to accommodate users who have JavaScript disabled. My validation isn't run from the form's onsubmit attribute, it's an event handler that is bound to a normal button in the form. So the button that kicks off the validation and submit isn't actually a submit, it's just type="button":

```
<input type="button" value="Ok" class="okbtn">
```

Then I register an event handler to its click event that does my validation. It submits if everything passes:

```
function clickHandler(event){
    thisForm = event.data.caller
    var valid = submitValidation(thisForm);
    if (valid == true){
        thisForm.submit();
    } else{
      }
}
```

My problem is if the user has JS disabled, there is no way to submit the form. I could make the button `type="submit"`, which would work for the JS-disabled users, but then it will *always submit the form and bypass the validation for the JS-enabled users. (The validation will run but it will submit anyway). If I make the button `type="submit"` can I block the submit event if it's clicked? I'm using JQuery, can JQuery suppress the submit? I want my validation to handle whether it gets submitted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can suppress submit clicks by doing something like:

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // prevents the form from being submitted
    clickHandler(); // the custom submit action
});
```

Or, you can suppress the actual form submit like this:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // etc
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the submit by setting the onsubmit handler in the `form` element, and then if it fails validation return false.

So you would return true if the validation succeeded, or false if it failed, instead of calling `thisForm.submit()`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the button to a normal submit button and bind the validation check to the [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event on the form.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if (!submitValidation()) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

From the docs:

> The `submit` event is sent to an
>   element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached
>   to  elements. Forms can be
>   submitted either by clicking an
>   explicit `<input type="submit">`,
>   `<input type="image">`, or `<button
>   type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form element has focus.