# Cancel form submit but allow enter key event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable Enter key submit on a form but allow the Enter key event to be registered for some other code I have listening. Is this possible?

```
$('#createPost :input').on("keypress", function(e) {

    if(e.target.id == 'post-author' && e.which == 13){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Is not working :( it still submits the form

Comment: Why not just instead prevent the submit event, then submit it manually on the submit button click? I don't like the idea of not being able to submit on pressing enter though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125470/supress-submit-event-submit-button-enabled-only-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: You could just prevent the default behaviour of the enter key in the other code that listens for keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `e.preventDefault()` to cancel submit action.

`return false;` from handler also works. And that works in more ancient browsers, even though this is not important with jQuery.

Comment: [WRONG, READ BELOW] adding on that: e.stopPropagation() works only on the jquery event chain

Comment: Yes and no. This method [do exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) in browsers, but it has no sense, since `submit` event does not bubble.

Comment: That's cool, but as soon as I e.preventDefault(), it cancels the code I have listening to the Enter key press

Comment: Hmm, `preventDefault` w/o `stopPropagation` should work. At least, on single element when no delegation is used.