# button color stay same after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 3 buttons in the top with color given.as i press the button it changes the color indicating that following button has been pressed and my submit form opens.as soon as i submit the form message displays "successful".but my problem is as i press the submit button the top button color changes to the previous one but i want it to stay the same.how can i do this please help!!!
here is my code:

this is my javascript and css fr changing the button colors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){
   $('.beforeClick').click(function (){
       $('.beforeClick').css('background-color',"#C1B0B3");
           $(this).css('background-color',"#9C7260");
   });
});

<style>
.beforeClick {
   margin-left: 0.4%;
   background-color:#C1B0B3;
    font-weight: bold;
  width: 14em;  
  height: 2em;
}
</style>
```

this is my buttons and its forms:

```
  <html>
        <body> 
     <button type="button" id="incbutton" class="beforeClick" style="background-color:#9C7260">Report1</button>

<button type="button" id="dthbutton"  class="beforeClick">Report2</button>

<button type="button" id="negbutton"  class="beforeClick"> Report3</button>


             <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#incbutton").click(function() {
            $("#form_sub_container1").show();
            $("#form_sub_container2").hide();
             $("#form_sub_container3").hide();
            })

            $("#dthbutton").click(function() {
            $("#form_sub_container2").show();
            $("#form_sub_container1").hide();
                $("#form_sub_container3").hide();
        })

        $("#negbutton").click(function() {
            $("#form_sub_container3").show();
            $("#form_sub_container1").hide();
                $("#form_sub_container2").hide();
        })
            </script>

           <div id="form_sub_container1" style="display:<?=  ( isset($_POST['rep']) || (!isset($_POST['report21']) && !isset($_POST['report31'])))? 'block':'none'?>">

        //report1 functionalities
        <input type="submit" name="rep" value="Save" id="btnsize1" /></td>
        </div>
          <div id="form_sub_container2" style="display: <?= isset($_POST['report21'])? 'block':'none'?>">

        //report2 functionalities
        <input type="submit" name="report21" value="Save" id="btnsize2" /></td>
        </div>

       <div id="form_sub_container3" style="display: <?= isset($_POST['report31'])? 'block':'none'?>">

        //report3 functionalities
        <input type="submit" name="report31" value="Save" id="btnsize3" /></td>
        </div>
        </body>
        <html>
```

this my report3:

```
<div id="form_sub_container3" style="display: <?= isset($_POST['report31'])? 'block':'none'?>">
<?php


if (isset($_POST['report31'])) 
 {
    $daydropdown111=$_POST['daydropdown111'];
    $monthdropdown111=$_POST['monthdropdown111'];
    $yeardropdown111=$_POST['yeardropdown111'];
    $dreport_place=$_POST['dreport_place'];
    $dreport_address=$_POST['dreport_address'];
    $dreport_additional=$_POST['dreport_additional'];
 }
 else 
 {
    $daydropdown111="";
    $monthdropdown111="";
    $yeardropdown111="";
    $dreport_place ="";
    $dreport_address="";
    $dreport_additional="";
 }

if (isset($_POST['report31'])) 
{

    $death = $DataAccessController->death_reports($_POST['daydropdown111'],$_POST['monthdropdown111'],$_POST['yeardropdown111'],$_POST['dreport_place'], $_POST['dreport_address'], $_POST['dreport_additional']);
    if ($death) {
          echo"<p><font  color=red  size='5pt' > Your  Report has been Registered</font></p>";

        }

}


?>

<div id="color" >
    <table>

            <h1 align="center"><p> Report</h1>


    <form action="" method="POST" id="form_id">

        <tr><td>Date </td><td>
            <select name="daydropdown111" id="daydropdown111"></select> 
            <select name="monthdropdown111" id="monthdropdown111"></select>
            <select name="yeardropdown111" id="yeardropdown111"></select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)

                    populatedropdown("daydropdown111", "monthdropdown111", "yeardropdown111")

            </script>

        </td></tr>

        <tr><td></br>  Place  </td><td></br><select name="dreport_place"id="wgtmsr">
        <option value="hospital" >Hospital</option><option value="residence">Residence</option><option value="others">Others</option></select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Address  </td><td></br><textarea name="dreport_address" rows="5" cols="32" id="loc" value=""> </textarea></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Additional Cases if any</td><td></br> <textarea name="dreport_additional" rows="5" cols="32" id="loc" value=""> </textarea></td></tr></label></td></tr>

        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="report31" value="Save" id="btnsiz"   /></td></tr>


    </form>
    </table></br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `id` instead of class and it is better if you'll create a function then make the `id` as the parameter for it.

Comment: how to make that..can u please help

Answer (score 0):

Nah..is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.beforeClick').click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color',"#C1B0B3");
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="incbutton" class="beforeClick" style="background-color:#9C7260" >Report1</button>
<button type="button" id="dthbutton" class="beforeClick">Report2</button>
<button type="button" id="negbutton" class="beforeClick">Report3</button>
```

Comment: no, actually these buttons are working like tabs.but each tabs have submit forms. after submitting, forms stay in the same page with the success msg displayed.but these buttons toggle. i want it to stay on the same tab.i.e that button should look pressed even after submitting form.

Comment: Oh, use AJAX then on success add css to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and call it whatever you want **eg:** `.clickedButton` or `.afterClick` and then when a form is submitted you do just like you did with `#form_sub_container` divs :

```
<div id="form_sub_container3" style="display: <?= isset($_POST['report31'])? 'block':'none'?>">
```

but this time you have to do it with your buttons, something like:

```
<button type="button" id="incbutton" class="<?= isset($_POST['rep'])? 'afterClick':'beforeClick'?>" >Report1</button>
<button type="button" id="dthbutton" class="<?= isset($_POST['report21'])? 'afterClick':'beforeClick'?>" >Report2</button>
<button type="button" id="negbutton" class="<?= isset($_POST['report31'])? 'afterClick':'beforeClick'?>" >Report3</button>
```

css

```
.afterClick{
     background-color:#9C7260;
}
```